# Is there a way of registering Hibernate Interceptor with Quarkus?

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, audit

I would like to use Hibernate Interceptor to get the changes that will be propagated to database so I can create some sort of Audit (with old and new values).

Hibernate offer the capability through Interceptor as mentioned here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch14.html

How can I register this interceptor (globally, for all sessions) using Quarkus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is still a question, but you have to use io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.PersistenceUnitExtension annotation to register your interceptor.

It is included in the quarkus hibernate orm dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For me, it works like a charm

```
@PersistenceUnitExtension
@Slf4j
public class EntityLoggerInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private final static AuditedEntity NO_ANNOTATION = new NoAnnotation();
    private final ThreadLocal<Set<LogRecord>> savedRecords = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashSet::new);
    private final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, AuditedEntity> auditedCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Inject
    SecurityService securityService;

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        AuditedEntity auditConfig = getAuditConfig(entity.getClass());
        if (auditConfig != null) {
            List<FieldData> fieldData = getEntityFieldDataStream(auditConfig.isIgnoreFieldsInConsoleByDefault(), auditConfig.isIgnoreFieldsInDatabaseByDefault(), entity, null, state, propertyNames, types)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (auditConfig.isAuditInConsole()) {
                createLogConsoleEntry(entity, (UUID) id, EventType.ENTITY_CREATED, fieldData.stream().filter(FieldData::isAuditInConsole).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
            if (auditConfig.isAuditInDatabase()) {
                createLogRecord(entity, (UUID) id, EventType.ENTITY_CREATED, fieldData.stream().filter(FieldData::isAuditInDatabase).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For auditing, your best bet right now is to use the Hibernate Envers extension.

I don't think you can register interceptors right now without developing a Quarkus extension.